# What is alternate solution for AD in Linux Environment with Windows System

Tags: authentication, authorization, single-sign-on, openldap, openam

Recently got project to Connect the system to Central Authentication and Authorization system like DC in windows enviorment but we have majroly Linux system in servers as well as clients with MySQL,youtrack etc open source serviceswe are using.
please suggest any open source solution which can be used to authenticate Linux as well as windows system along with Apllications like youtrack,github,OTRS,MYSQL etc..
Thanks,,,,